# Iterating through character of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string which I need to do a certain operation on

```
string="_,_,_,56"
```

When I iterate through the elements of the string I am getting an output as

```
_
,
_
,
_
,
2
4
```

I want the output as :

```
_ _ _ 56
```

That means I do not want `','` to be considered as a character and I want the two-digit number to be considered as a single character.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
string = "_,_,_,56"
new_string = string.split(",")
print(new_string)
# ['_', '_', '_', '56']
```

The `str.split()` method allows you to split a single string into a list of strings, using the given character as a separator.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Two</del> Three simple ways using `str` methods [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```py
>>> string="_,_,_,56"
>>> print(string.replace(',', ' '))
_ _ _ 56
>>> print(' '.join(string.split(',')))
_ _ _ 56
```

Another version thanks to @Blckknght is using the `*` operator to unpack the `split`ted list:

```py
>>> print(*string.split(','))
_ _ _ 56
```

Comment: For printing out the results, `print(*string.split(','))` also works, since the default separator is a space.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the remark! edited that right in